# Delete 4-spaces as a single tab

Tags: indentation, deletion

I asked another question yesterday but this bothers me a little. I use 4 spaces as indentation for programming (ShellScript, C and Python, mostly). When I want to delete the 4 spaces, I had to do one by one. When I was using `vim`, I didn't have to do in that way.

What I want to set up is that, when you put the cursor at the beginning of the first word after indentation and press `DEL`, it deletes the 4 spaces at once.

An example:

```
int main () {
    ▮int a = 0;
    if (a = 0) {
        printf("Hello!");
    }
    return 0;
}


int main () {
▮int a = 0;
    if (a = 0) {
        printf("Hello!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(Suppose that ▮ is with the `i`).

Is it possible to do that in emacs?

---

Result of doing `C-u C-x =` on the indentation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in `emacs -Q` that `C-u <backspace>` will delete 4 spaces **backwards**.

Equivalent bindings would be:

- `M-4 <backspace>`
- `C-4 <backspace>`

*Before*

```c
int main () {
    ▮int a = 0;
```

(▮ represents `point`)

*Do `C-u <backspace>` or `C-u DEL`.*

*After*

```c
int main () {
▮int a = 0;
```

By default `C-u` represents a repetition or **4** for most commands (usually navigation related).

---

**Update**

To delete 4 space to the **right** of the cursor, do `C-u C-d` instead.

*Before*

```c
int main () {
▮    int a = 0;
```

(▮ represents `point`)

*Do `C-u C-d`.*

*After*

```c
int main () {
▮int a = 0;
```

---

On emacs 25.1.50.x (emacs master branch as of now), `<backspace>` or `DEL` is bound to the `backward-delete-char-untabify` command by default.

Comment: I understand what you tell me, but I don't convert the spaces to TABs or viceversa in real time, I have changed it in the config for every indentation.

Comment: Hmm, then I do not understand your question.. the question says "Kill 4-spaces .."

Comment: From the cursor to the point of where the 4 spaces start. It's like treating 4-spaces as a unique tab, not converting it in real time to delete it.

Comment: @captainepoch It's not clear if you are trying to delete 4 ASCII Space characters (0x20) or an ASCII TAB character (0x09). What do you see when you do `C-u C-x =` with cursor on the area that you call "4 spaces".

Comment: I see this (I hope it's what you asked for, large image, that's why I didn't use MD's image syntax) https://i.imgur.com/3I4a2Ep.png

Comment: @captainepoch OK, I added the same code in `c-mode` in an `emacs -Q` session and I still cannot recreate your scenario. From the `C-u C-x =` result (very helpful!), I see that there's a `before-string` overlay active where the cursor is. I do not use `c-mode` and so I am not very familiar with it. Do you have any other minor mode or c-mode setting enabled that would put those overlays?

Comment: No, I don't. I tried on an HTML file on `web-mode`, but nothing about `before-string` appeared... At `c-mode` I got this settings: https://github.com/captainepoch/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs.d/config/c_dev.el

Comment: @captainepoch Actually, nevermind, those overlays are related to `linum-mode`. So those characters do look like physical spaces (tabs) because the ASCII code is 0x20. If you can `C-f`/`C-b` 4 times in that indentation, that's another proof that those are physical space characters. Then the above solution should work for you. *In your screenshot, did you select all the spaces and then do `C-u C-x =`? Why does the whole indentation before `return` look selected?*

Comment: I selected it, yeah. This is a screenshot without selecting the indentation (http://i.imgur.com/AQl7uic.png). What I want is deleting the 4 spaces as a tab with the DEL key.

Comment: @captainepoch That's a perfect screenshot! So basically those are just spaces; forget that you hit TAB to make that indentation. So one DEL will delete just one space. To delete all 4 spaces to the *left* of the cursor, do `C-u DEL` as I mentioned above in the answer. If you want to delete 4 spaces to the *right* of the cursor, do `C-u C-d`.

Comment: @captainepoch I have updated the answer; hope it is clearer.

Comment: It does, I'll try to make a function to do the work pressing `DEL`. Much appreciated, Kaushal Modi :)

Comment: `C-u <backspace>` deletes EXACTLY 4 characters. It does not respect tab stops. It does not respect indentation settings. It will do the wrong thing if there are tab (or other) characters instead of spaces. It just so happens that one `C-u` means "repeat four times" which is a common indentation width. This answer addresses the letter of the question, but I think an answer that would be more in the spirit of the question (delete whitespace characters until the previous tab stop) would be more useful.